# Bootstrap default navbar is smaller than it should be by default even on fresh install

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, express, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi I am working on an mobile web application that is using Node.js, expressJS, jquery v2.1.3, and twitter-bootstrap v3.3.2. Last night I noticed whenever I was testing the application the navbar I was using looked smaller than all the other bootstrapped navbars I had used in the past(the text was smaller and the height of it when it should be collapsed), and it wasn't collapsing properly. I obviously began to inspect anything and everything I could to try and see where this navbar anomaly was coming from. So more insight on the situation. If I selected the corner or my browser window and drag it to make it re-size the navbar functions properly. If I inspect it in mobile device mode with chrome or use the browser on my mobile device to access the application that is when they are behaving poorly. Once my navbar stumped me I decided to create a new empty web application and have it only contain a navbar and some filler text to remove any code that my navbar might be inheriting that I am unaware of. This failed as well. I went online and downloaded a fresh dist of jquery and bootstrap and put them into the project. I then went and got the boilerplate code for a default nav-bar from bootply.com and added it in. This did not work even on my fresh install example. I am having the same issue with the size of the nav-bar being smaller than it should be  when the application is run on a mobile device or inspected in chrome as a mobile device, but not when I just simply resize the browser to be smaller to imitate mobile. Below I have included the following:

- **[Link to application hosted on Heroku.][2]**
- **Relevant code**

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">

  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/jQuery/dist/jquery.js">  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/bootstrap-3.3.2-dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/bootstrap-3.3.2-dist/css/bootstrap.css"/>

  </head>

  <body><!--Body starts here-->

  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container" style="margin-top:50px">
    <div class="text-center">
      <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
      <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any      new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML  document.</p>
    </div>

  </div><!-- /.container -->
  ```

**Edit 1 more insightful information thank you to Hager Aly for the idea.**
[Here is a link to an imgur album.][3]It contains two screenshots. One is when I am inspecting my application's navbar and the other is when I am inspecting a default navbar on getbootstrap.com. When I access my application from a mobile device it appears the same as the first screen shot. In the past It has always looked like the second one.

If there is anything more information I can provide you please let me know. Thank you for your time in advance. Sincerely,

--Fredk

Comment: seems okay for me the same as the bootstrap official site, i'm using firefox by the way

i know it might be silly, can you try to press  "ctrl + 0" to reset the window zoom to default

Comment: Are you using a firefox browser on a mobile device? When I try and access my heroku application using the firefox browsers on my phone I still am receiving the tiny navigation bar.

Comment: can you attach a screenshot.

works okay on ie, windows phone

Comment: Sure not a problem. [Here is a link to an imgur album that contains two images.](http://imgur.com/a/pz734) The first is a picture of when I inspect the navbar that is on my application in a mobile view. The second is when I inspect the first default navbar example provided from getbootstrap.com's components page. The first image is how the page is appearing when I open it on all browsers on my mobile device. The second provided by getbootstrap is how my navbars have always appeared in the past. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Try changing your calls to the bootstrap files from a local source to a CDN. Try [this](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/).

Comment: I believe that your solution would work as well. I feel like the bootstrap files I was using were causing this error. Getting a good working set of them was the key. I believed that solved this so using the stable CDNs you provided should have also fixed this as well. Thank you.
**EDIT:** So I went back and plugged in the CDN for science sake, and as expected it worked as well. Thank you again you are all so awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. I believe the issue lied somewhere in the bootstrap distribution I was using. I deleted the distribution I had gotten from getbootstrap.com and just downloaded one using bower. With the new bootstrap dist installed the navbar behaves accordingly again. I know this answer may not be of much help, but I believe there was something missing in my initial bootstrap distribution files.

Condensed: The bootstrap files I was using were not working properly. Getting a working version of them or using reliable CDN enabled my navigation bar to operate properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

add that  line to the head element

Comment: I did this did not fix the problem. I had a coleague mention that my boostrap distribution does not contain a bootstrap.less file. Do you think this is the issue?

Comment: Less is a pre-processor for CSS. It adds functionality such as variables for CSS that is then compiled in to plain old CSS.

Comment: i just tried it through chrome dev tools it works, about less i don't think so